Is there a way to install a CA Certificate onto an Android Automotive Emulator?
I want to inspect some HTTPS calls / write some test for my android auto app, and would like to use Charles Web Proxy to do this.
I am able to connect to the proxy using the Emulator's extended controls as normal, and I can drag and drop (or adb push) the PEM file to the emulator as well. The normal route of downloading from charlesproxy.com/getssl isn't an options as the auto emulator doesn't have a browser, though I could install one I guess.
Anyway, the issue becomes the settings app on Android Auto OS. It does not have the Security & Privacy section to choose a cert to install. It is definitely possible though, as I can use something like HTTP Toolkit to see unencrypted HTTPS calls.
Unfortunately, Charles is our only current integrated tool for automated testing, so I do not have the time to figure out a way to automate tests with HTTP Toolkit.
I attempted to install the cert with various ADB commands, but those proved unsuccessful, due to permission errors, Android OS issues, etc.

If it is for your app then you can make your app trust an installed "user" CA certificate or directly embed the cert into your app: https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-config#TrustingDebugCa
